# How to write a wrapper around a templated class that modifies the template parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, generics, design-patterns

We have a templated class `A` and derived classes `A1` and `A2`:

```
template<typename T> class A {
};

template<typename T> class A1: public A<T>{
};

template<typename T> class A2: public A<T>{
};
```

I need a wrapper that accepts any class of type `A*`, ie any derived type of `A`, as a template parameter and modify its template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename Atype> class WrapperA {
   Atype<pair<T, int>> atypeobj;
};
```

Hoping to be used as follows:

```
WrapperA<int, A1<int>> w1;
WrapperB<int, A2<int>> w2;
```

The `WrapperA` needs to work only with derived classes of `A`.

Comment: What does "modify its template parameter" mean? Your question is unclear. Please [edit] your question and add examples of ***specific*** template invocations, and what your expected results are.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.   A raw pointer of type `A<T> *` will be able to point at an instance of `A1<T>` or `A2<T>`  (as long as you take care to ensure that pointer is initialised to point at a valid object) and you can use that in your "wrapper".   Alternatively, use one of the standard smart pointesr (e.g. a `std::unique_ptr<A<T> >`  - again, you need to take care to initialise the smart pointer appropriately.

Comment: you probably need the nested template syntaxe:
  template<typename T, typename Atype<typename>> class WrapperA {
     Atype<pair<T, int>> atypeobj;
  }

Comment: your way of using the terms is a little confusing. You do not "change" the template arguments of `A1`. Rather you want some `A1<pair<T,int>>` given some `A1<T>`.

Comment: btw typos in posted code distract from the actual question. You should make sure the code you posted compiles / has no errors that are irrelevant to the quesiton. Missing `;` are easily added, but its even easier if you add them rather than everybody who tries to compile your code

Comment: Inheritance between `An` and `A` seems irrelevant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly state `int` as argument. The template and its argument can be dissected from a given instantiation by partial specialization (provided that all derived have same number of arguments). The fact that there is a base class `A` is actually not that relevant when the derived classes are templates too.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct A {  };    
template <typename T> struct A1 : A<T> {};

// primary template (no definition needed)
template<typename Atype> struct WrapperA;
// specialization when Atype is instantiation of a template D with 
// one type argument T
template <template <typename> typename D,typename T> struct WrapperA<D<T>> {
    D<std::pair<T,int>> atypeobj;
};
```

Then use it

```
WrapperA<A1<int>> w;
```

Comment: Awesome this is what I am looking for. I will let you know once it compiled.

Comment: Btw I need this to work only for children of class A, so I think I will combine it with your previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your `typename Atype` parameter into a **template template parameter**, eg:

```
template<typename T> class A { };
template<typename T> class A1: public A<T>{ };
template<typename T> class A2: public A<T>{ };

template<typename T, template <typename> typename Atype>
class WrapperA {
   Atype<pair<T, int>> atypeobj;
};

WrapperA<int, A1> w1;
WrapperB<int, A2> w2;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Z489Qa)